# Need help to parse text file

Tags: powershell

I need help in understanding a logic how I can parse a text file which is currently not in proper format, due to which it's very hard to read the content of the log. Text input file looks like below:

```
========== Test1 (1) ========== Id UTC Date/Time Message 4d1eb19c-5420-4bb2-9e21-65880eb90429 08-30T01:26:24Z Messagel Name='abz', Connection='Usb', Fleet Report Id='ca9d3457-1564-4066-8f5e-12345678', Fleet Proxy Id ='ghjfda7-c7e8-4bb2-9dd4-2f4c3b2498a3,4d1eb19c-5420-4bb2-9e21-65880eb90429  08-30T01:26:24Z  Message2 Name='abz', Connection='Usb', Fleet Report Id='ca9d3457-1564-4066-8f5e-12345678', Fleet Proxy Id ='ghjfda7-c7e8-4bb2-9dd4-2f4c3b2498a3.,4d1eb19c-5420-4bb2-9e21-65880eb90429  08-30T01:26:24Z  Message2 Name='abz', Connection='Usb', Fleet Report Id='ca9d3457-1564-4066-8f5e-12345678', Fleet Proxy Id ='ghjfda7-c7e8-4bb2-9dd4-2f4c3b2498a3.

========== Test2 (1) ========== Id UTC Date/Time Message 4d1eb19c-5420-4bb2-9e21-65880eb90429 08-30T01:26:24Z Message2 Name='xyz', Connection='Usb', Fleet Report Id='ca9d09e7-1564-4066-8f5e-6a123456', Fleet Proxy Id ='0fsfsda7-c7e8-4bb2-9dd4-2f4c3b2498a3,4d1eb19c-5420-4bb2-9e21-65880eb90429  08-30T01:26:24Z  Message2 Name='abz', Connection='Usb', Fleet Report Id='ca9d3457-1564-4066-8f5e-12345678', Fleet Proxy Id ='ghjfda7-c7e8-4bb2-9dd4-2f4c3b2498a3.,4d1eb19c-5420-4bb2-9e21-65880eb90429  08-30T01:26:24Z  Message2 Name='abz', Connection='Usb', Fleet Report Id='ca9d3457-1564-4066-8f5e-12345678', Fleet Proxy Id ='ghjfda7-c7e8-4bb2-9dd4-2f4c3b2498a3.
```

There are multiple sections {Test1 test2 ...n}, and each sections contains multiple Id utc Date Time and message also all sections start with

and end with

How to arrange them in a tabular format? Need output to be formatted as below in tabular format:

```
ID UTC Date/Time Message

========== Test1 (1) ==========

Id                                    UTC Date/Time    Message 
4d1eb19c-5420-4bb2-9e21-65880eb90429  08-30T01:26:24Z  Messagel Name='abz', Connection='Usb', Fleet Report Id='ca9d3457-1564-4066-8f5e-12345678', Fleet Proxy Id ='ghjfda7-c7e8-4bb2-9dd4-2f4c3b2498a3.

4d1eb19c-5420-4bb2-9e21-65880eb90429  08-30T01:26:24Z  Message2 Name='abz', Connection='Usb', Fleet Report Id='ca9d3457-1564-4066-8f5e-12345678', Fleet Proxy Id ='ghjfda7-c7e8-4bb2-9dd4-2f4c3b2498a3.

4d1eb19c-5420-4bb2-9e21-65880eb90429  08-30T01:26:24Z  Message3 Name='abz', Connection='Usb', Fleet Report Id='ca9d3457-1564-4066-8f5e-12345678', Fleet Proxy Id ='ghjfda7-c7e8-4bb2-9dd4-2f4c3b2498a3.

========== Test2 (1) ========== 
Id                                    UTC Date/Time   Message 
4d1eb19c-5420-4bb2-9e21-65880eb90429  08-30T01:26:24Z Message1 Name='xyz', Connection='Usb', Fleet Report Id='ca9d09e7-1564-4066-8f5e-6a123456', Fleet Proxy Id ='0fsfsda7-c7e8-4bb2-9dd4-2f4c3b2498a3,

4d1eb19c-5420-4bb2-9e21-65880eb90429  08-30T01:26:24Z  Message2 Name='abz', Connection='Usb', Fleet Report Id='ca9d3457-1564-4066-8f5e-12345678', Fleet Proxy Id ='ghjfda7-c7e8-4bb2-9dd4-2f4c3b2498a3,

4d1eb19c-5420-4bb2-9e21-65880eb90429  08-30T01:26:24Z  Message3 Name='abz', Connection='Usb', Fleet Report Id='ca9d3457-1564-4066-8f5e-12345678', Fleet Proxy Id ='ghjfda7-c7e8-4bb2-9dd4-2f4c3b2498a3.
```

This is what i have tried but it is not parsing all the content inside the text file.

```
$file = Get-Content -path .\ViewSource.txt | Where-Object {
  $_ -ne ""
} | ForEach-Object {
  $_ -replace '<[^>]+>', ''
}
foreach ($line in $file) {
  $elements = $line.Split(" ", [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
  [PSCustomObject]@{
    Id          = $elements[8]
    UtcDateTime = $elements[9]
    Message     = $elements[10..19] -join " "
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to show how all sections start and end. Also it's not clear how the source file looks when there are multiple sections. For the posted bit you can use something like ```(Get-Content .\1.txt) -replace '^(=+ .+? =+) (.+)', "`$1`r`n`r`n`$2`r`n" | Out-File r:\2.txt -Encoding utf8```

Comment: Please show us something you have tried first. It is expected that you have at least shown some effort. As of now this reads as a code writing request which is not what SO is here for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help...It starts with <p> ========== Test1 (1) ========== Id UTC Date.. </p>

Answer (score 0):

Since your ID and Timestamp fields have a fixed width, and there don't seem to be multiple messages per line, the simplest approach would probably be to replace the "inline" headers with a properly formatted/wrapped header line:

```
$inline  = ' Id UTC Date/Time Message '
$wrapped = "`nId                                   UTC Date/Time   Message`n"
(Get-Content -Path 'C:\path\to\input.txt') -replace $inline, $wrapped |
    Set-Content -Path 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
```

**Edit:** if you have multiple messages per line you also need to match the sequences of GUID and timestamp that precede each message and insert linebreaks before those matches:

```
$inline  = ' Id UTC Date/Time Message '
$wrapped = "`nId                                   UTC Date/Time   Message"

$guid = '[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}'
$ts   = '\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z'

(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt') -replace $inline, $wrapped -replace "($guid) +($ts) +", "`n`$1 `$2 " |
    Set-Content -Path 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But text file has multiple messages in one line starting of the message <p> and ends with </p> and need all the messages to be formatted in tabular format with heading ID Date/Time and message. Once again thank you so much for your time.